# Convert array to XML with both tags on empty value

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I need to convert an array to XML string but I would like to create both open and close tags if my array contains empty values for a certain key, like ***'testone'*** and ***'testtwo'*** below.

For example in my code:

```
$test_array = array (
  'testone' => array(),
  'bla' => 'blub',
  'testtwo' => '',
  'foo' => 'bar',
  'another_array' => array (
    'stack' => 'overflow',
  ),
);
function array_to_xml( $data, &$xml_data ) {
    foreach( $data as $key => $value ) {
        if( is_numeric($key) ){
            $key = 'item'.$key; //dealing with <0/>..<n/> issues
        }
        if( is_array($value) ) {
            $subnode = $xml_data->addChild($key);
            array_to_xml($value, $subnode);
        } else {
            $xml_data->addChild("$key",htmlspecialchars("$value"));
        }
     }
}

$xml_data = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0"?><data></data>');
array_to_xml($test_array,$xml_data);
$result = $xml_data->asXML();
echo $result;
```

I get this result :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <testone/>
    <bla>blub</bla>
    <testtwo/>
    <foo>bar</foo>
    <another_array>
        <stack>overflow</stack>
    </another_array>
</data>
```

But I need this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <testone></testone>
    <bla>blub</bla>
    <testtwo></testtwo>
    <foo>bar</foo>
    <another_array>
        <stack>overflow</stack>
    </another_array>
</data>
```

Comment: Isn't it (in terms of XML) the same?

Comment: It is. But I don't go for validity. I need it to be this way because my script edits an already existing XML and someone else is verifying after the certain edits using a hash. So it needs to be this way.